# Application of Intermediate Value Theorem in a proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $p(x)_{x \in \mathbb R} = x^n + a_{n - 1}x^{n  - 1} + \ldots + a_1x + a_0$ be a polynomial. Then all the zeroes of $p$ are in $(-M, M)$ where $M = 1 + \max\{|a_{n - 1}|,\ldots, |a_1|, |a_0|\}$.

Proof:

> Let $r(x)_{x \ne 0} = \frac{p(x)}{x^n} - 1$. Then for $|x| > 1, \ $ $|r(x)| < \frac{M}{|x| - 1}$ meaning $|x| \ge M$ implies $|r(x)| < 1$. Now we have $p(x) = x^n(1 + r(x))$ for $|x| \ge M$ where $1 + r(x) > 0$ since $|r(x)| < 1.$ It follows $p(x)$ and $x^n$ have same sign for $|x| \ge M$ meaning $\color{red}{\text{ any zero of $p$ must be in $(-M, M)$}}.$

How does the $\color{red}{\text{part in red}}$ above follow? If $|x| < M$, then $x \in (-M, M)$ and  $p(x), x^n$ will have opposite signs. How does that connect to $p(-M) \le 0 \le p(M)$ (or $p(-M) \ge 0 \ge p(M))$ granted they are using the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: Not sure I follow the part that says if $|r(x)| < \frac{M}{|x| - 1}$ then $|x| \ge M$ implies $|r(x)| <1$. Certainly if $|x| \ge M+1$ it follows.

Comment: If $p(x)$ and $x^n$ have the same sign, then $x\neq0\implies p(x)\neq 0$.  So, since $p(x)$ and $x^n$ have the same sign when $|x|\geq M$, then zeros of $p(x)$ can lie only in $(-M,M)$.

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry to bother you, but am I missing something in that the above analysis requires $|x|> M+1$ to ensure $|r(x)| <1$?

Comment: @copper.hat I didn't read the whole proof, I was just responding to the question at the end.  I'll take a look now.

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry, didn't mean to ask you to spend more time, was just curious.

Comment: @copper.hat No problem, I'll be glad to try.

Comment: @saulspatz Don't spend the time, I think the proof above is a bit sloppy. Assuming no bugs, I will post a slight modification.

Comment: @saulspatz, how does $p(x) > 0, x^n > 0 \implies x \ne 0$?

Comment: @user691848 If $p(x)$ and $x^n$ have the same sign, you can't have $p(x)>0,\ x^n<0$.  What did you mean to ask?

Comment: @saulspatz, you must've answered before I edited my post. I meant to ask how the fact that $p(x), x^n$ having the same sign implies $x \ne 0.$

Comment: If $|x|\geq M$ then $x \neq 0$ so $x^n\neq 0$.  But $p(x)$ has the same sign as $x^n$ so $p(x)\neq0$.

Answer (score 2):

I think the proof has a small bug that is easily corrected. Also, I don't think the intermediate value theorem is needed.

The only real change is that $M$ is replaced by $M-1$ below.

Suppose $|x| \ge M$.

You have
\begin{eqnarray}
|{p(x) \over x^n} -1| &\le& {|a_{n-1}| \over |x|}+ \cdots + {|a_{0}| \over |x|^n} \\
&\le& \color{red}{(M-1)} ({1 \over |x|}+ \cdots + {1 \over |x|^n} )\\
&<& (M-1) ( {1 \over 1-{1 \over |x|}} -1) \\
&=& {M-1 \over |x|-1} \\ 
&\le& 1
\end{eqnarray}
In particular you have
$-1 < {p(x) \over x^n} -1 < 1$ or
$0 < {p(x) \over x^n} < 2$
and so $p(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: Why does it matter $p(x)$ and $x^n$ have the same sign? If $p(x) = -s(x)$, then we get $0> \frac{s(x)}{x^n} > - 2$ and so $p(x)$ falls out the picture entirely. Is that why? Any other reason? Thanks.

Comment: In my proof it doesn't matter, it shows that $p(x) \neq 0$ directly. You don't need the intermediate value theorem this way. I think the proof in the question is a little sloppy and involves more reasoning than necessary.

Comment: +1. Sometimes a change of variable can give a much sharper bound. E.g. if $p(x)=x^5-x^4+77$ then $p(x)=0\implies |x|<78.$ Let $x=ky$ with $k>0.$ Then $p(x)=0\implies y^5-y^4/k+77/k^5=0\implies |y|<1+\max (1/k,77/k^5)\implies$ $\implies |x|<k+k\max(1,77/k^4)......$ With $k=3$ this gives $|x|<6$...... Also, if $a_0\ne 0$ then letting $x=1/y,$ we can obtain a positive lower bound for $\{|x|:p(x)=0\}.$

Comment: I see $x_n$ in 3 places. I think should be $x^n.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you for catching my sloppiness! Much appreciated.